# trunc the integer number from real number using matlab

Tags: matlab, numbers, cut

please, any one help me to trunct the integer number from real number without any round to nearest  integers in matlab ,e.g: if i have  255/64=3.98 I need just 3 not 4. I used fix  in my program but not work. my cod is:

```
S=imread('image0286.jpg')/64; 
   disp(fix(S);
```

this give me the output after rounds the elements of S to the nearest integers not cut the integer.

Answer (score 4):

`fix` does do what you want.

```
>>fix(255/64)
    ans =
          3
```

maybe some other part of your code isn't doing what you think it is doing. could you post more code and your expected and real output

EDIT:
Imread returns the values as uint8, and division in this class seems to carry out the rounding you don't want. try recasting to double before dividing

```
S = double(imread('image0286.jpg'))/64
```

Comment: I Need to reduce the color space from 256 to 4 that I divid the image after read it by 64, when I try to compute the color histogram I found the color becom 5 not 4 because it round to nearest integer numbers.

Comment: np. do consider upvoting/accepting good answers to your questions, as this is considered good so etiquette. c.f. @Jonas comment to your question.

Answer (score 0):

`floor(x)` does this, though beware of negative numbers.

but `fix` should work too.

Also note that `imread` might return a `byte` array or `int` array rather than floats. so your division might be int-division, and automatically truncate without the need for `fix` or `floor`.

Comment: I try the floor in my program also it round to nearest integer, plrase I need to get e.g:

3.1=3 ; 3.2=3; 3.5=3; 3.7=3; 3.9=3

Comment: if this is the case, you are doing something wrong. please show us the output of `S(1,:)`. perhaps this is already rounded.